# How can I create a web application using Angular frontend and Node backend and Git hub API starting from OAuth?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, oauth, github-api

I mean to say how the flow should be between my client and server and github server. Starting in OAuth only I am not getting it and also I am stuck in an error for making get request. From where should I make the get request, client or server for OAuth. What is a better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First take a look at this diagram (Made by me with draw.io).**

[image: Flowchart Diagram]

Diagram explained:

As you can see there is no reference to MEAN stack in this diagram because this doesn't have anything to do with language preferences you choose.

Your client could be **Angularjs | jQuery | ReactJS | ember | knockout | backbone | iOS | 
Android| ...**.

Your server could be : **node.js | php | python | java | ruby|....** .

Your database could be : **mongodb | mysql | postgresql | couchdb|....**

Understanding OAuth API:

**OAuth API allow users to simply login from one app to another with the same credentials based on one place.**

Furthermore it allows Single Sign On easily on different client apps.

The basic behind OAuth relies on one sign up and many log-ins. 
Couple years ago, when you wanted to login to an app or a service you would have to sign-up.
then if you wanted login to a different service you would have to sign up again with obviously the same details ( Email, Birthdate, Username, Password, Photo, Gender... ) just to a different service.

**That is madness, and made us as users impatient, writing those details every single time.**

That was long time ago and now:
You sign up once to Facebook | Google Plus | GitHub | Twitter , and you can simply login to a different app or a service with those credentials powered by those companies, in return those companies will supply you as a software provider those details ( Email, Photo, Gender, Username, Friends, Followers ) which is a lot of data in less effort for the user himself.

> After you have basic understanding of OAuth: Lets move on to the FLOW:

I'm going to write the flow by phases:

First Action:
User opens your app.

Second Action:
User can pick log-in with GitHub | Most likely you would also offer him to sign-up with his email.

Third Action:
User picks github login -> a popup by github is opened.
Three possibilities:

**A) User has an account and logged in.**

**-> Simply press accept, GitHub returns a callback with Access Token, and generic data about  the user.**

**B) User has an account and not logged in.**

**-> Simply enters login credentials (Email | Username & Password) -> Phase A.**

**C) User doesn't have an account.
-> User sign up to Git Hub -> Phase B -> Phase A.**

Now: you have couple of actions needs to be taken:
**In GitHub you have to supply information about -> Successful Login Redirect.
That means: URL to redirect after successful login.**

When you fill that url in the settings, after the user has logged in, **he will be automatically be redirected to that URL and with that request will be sent his details.**

**As soon as you get the details from GitHub API, you would want to save the user into the database on your server.**

> Why?

So the actions made by the user on your app will be saved.

Basically, I save everything: Data and Access Token.

> Why do I need access token?
>   **If you ever wanted to make actions on his GitHub profile, for example fork new repos, or follow other members, you would have to use this access token.**

If I left anything unclear, I'd be more than happy to explain more.

@linial

Comment: Thank you. It's very neat explanation. When I try to follow it in my Angular Client. I am not able to call api's from other domains(CORS) or access is denied. Do you have any idea about the error?

Comment: Hi @HHH did my answer helped you? If so I'd really appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct, and upvote it. if no, let me know how can i help.

Comment: Yes, I have created it or else provide me any reference to implement step by step oAuth for any provider.

Comment: @HHH take a look at https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-passport or my favorite, https://github.com/sahat/satellizer for Oauth in Angular / Express